# Highlight unique value in row

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting, countif, excel-2016

I have data that I would like to highlight if it is unique in the row.

The data is an export from a **`SQL`** Table and I want to check that the data is setup correctly.

For example:

```
Product     Plvl1       Plvl2       Plvl3       Plvl4
Product1     3.9         3.9        **4.1**   3.9
Product2     1.135       1.135       1.135     1.135
Product3    4            **5**       4        4
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a conditional formatting rule based upon the following formula,

```
=countif($b:$e, b2)=1
```

[image]

Comment: Does this work on a per row basis? If you have a value that is unique row 2, and the same value on row 3, but it is unique to row 3, I think this doesn't work.

Comment: I think changing to =countif($B2:$E2,B2)=1 makes it work for unique per row.

Answer (score 3):

Select each Row alone or change apply to for each Row

You can use `Highlight Cells`, `Duplicate Values` and instead of Duplicate use the arrow and choose `Unique` and choose the Format you want

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Agree with Jeeped's answer. There is one more way that you could do this,

- Select the range of cells that you want
- click conditional formatting --> highlight cell rules --> duplicate values
- select unique in the dropdown, select a color of your choice and press OK